# Spring Data index autocreate

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible for Spring Data Mongo to create indexes automatically based on Repository methods? Maybe there is some third-party plugin or annotation? Maybe there is an API (provides requested fields) that can help me with this task?

Comment: whats the usecase for this? Spring can automatically create indices by annotating your entity properties with for example: @Indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In annotation `@EnableMongoRepositories` you need set property `createIndexesForQueryMethods`([(doc)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html#createIndexesForQueryMethods--)) to `true` and enable automatic index creation[(doc)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.index-creation).